# Error while freeing structs inside GHash

Tags: c, hash, free, glib

So Im trying to fully free my HashTable, but im getting this error and I don't know how to fix it:

```
program(77439,0x7fffa18e9340) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fa0096b7208: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

The Hash was created this way:

```
GHashTable* users = g_hash_table_new_full(g_direct_hash,g_direct_equal,NULL,destroyUser);
```

The USER struct is defined this way:

```
typedef struct user {
    gpointer id;
    char username[256]; 
    int post_count; 
    char short_bio[16384]; 
    int reputation;
}*USER;
```

And this is my free function:

```
void destroyUser(gpointer x) {
struct user *n = (struct user *) x; 
if (n) {
    free(n -> username);
    free(n -> short_bio);
    free(n);
}
}
```

Im not understanding why it isn't capable of freeing the Hash.... If anyone can help, I'll be glad :)

Comment: aaaargh don't free arrays! just free `n`

Comment: You can't free `username` because it was never allocated with `malloc`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  i thought I had to free the arrays too.... Thank you so much guys!! :)

Comment: @PedroLima já posso acabar isto xD

Answer (score 0):

Your free:ing function should be just:

```
void destroyUser(gpointer x)
{
  free(x);
}
```

Or, just pass `free` as the last argument, no need to wrap it in a function of your own. Also:

- There's no need to `NULL`-check before passing a pointer to `free()`,  since `free(NULL)` is well-defined.
- You must not free the embedded arrays, they have not been allocated individually using `malloc()` but are part of the entire structure's allocation.
- Perhaps you should use `g_malloc()` and `g_free()` since it's a glib program?